# How to set inital state from props after fetch?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to get data using fetch() and pass it down my component hierarchy, and use that data to set the initial state of one of my components

I have tried setting the inital state using the props and passing them down.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        getFileSystem().then(response => {
            if (response.success) {
                this.setState({
                    filesystem: response.filesystem,
                    projects: response.projects
                })
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                filesystem: {
                    name: '/',
                    type: 'directory',
                    children: [
                        { name: 'error.txt', type: 'file', data: 'error' }
                    ]
                },
                projects: []
            })
        })

    }
```

```
class TerminalContainer extends Component { 

    constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                filesystem: props.filesystem,
                terminal_data: [''],
                current_dir_name: '/',
                current_dir: props.filesystem,
                full_path: ""
            }
        }
...
```

But the component calls the constructor function before the data is loaded into the props of the component. This means that the inital state of the component is not set properly.

I need some way of preventing the component from being rendered until all of the data is ready

Comment: *I need some way of preventing the component* - there's no way. If you need to postpone the initialization of a component, do this in parent component.

Comment: in the parent component you can write this line `{this.state.filesystem && <TerminalContainer filesystem={this.state.filesystem} />` to prevent the initialisation of `TerminalContainer` when filesytem is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the props given to a component as initial state, and these props are state in a parent component that are fetched asynchronously, you need to delay the rendering of the child component.

You could e.g. add an additional piece of state called `isLoading` that you set to `false` when the fetch is complete and use that to conditionally render the `TerminalContainer` component.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    filesystem: null,
    projects: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getFileSystem()
      .then(response => {
        if (response.success) {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            filesystem: response.filesystem,
            projects: response.projects
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          filesystem: {
            name: "/",
            type: "directory",
            children: [{ name: "error.txt", type: "file", data: "error" }]
          },
          projects: []
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, filesystem } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return null;
    }
    return <TerminalContainer filesystem={filesystem} />;
  }
}
```